# Redirect to several pages during authentication ASP.CORE

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

On my ASP.CORE app I have use User Identity authentication.

I want do next: when user visit the site IF he not authorized on the site - show him home page but IF he was authorized before - show him another page (Encrypt controller page in my example). **BUT** IF he navigate from Home page to /Encrypt , program should redirect him to login page (how it's works now).

Here on startup in Configure I tried to redirect to another page /Encrypt (default) when user visit the site  IF user was authorized before - all works (he redirecting to /Encrypt page) BUT if he was`t authorized before, program  will  redirect him to Login page on Account Controller. **That's is the problem.**

*I've note that Account Controller don't start If user was authorized before (only when not authorized before (without auth cookies)) so I can't redirect using Account Contoller.*
So, where intercept request (or read about it) or where performs checking for cookies for authorize? Or what to do with this?

My Startup setting:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();
    ...

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Encrypt}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
```

My Account Controller looks like:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager, SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["UserName"] = this.GetUserName();
        return View(new LoginViewModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result =
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
 return View(model);
}
```

My Encrypt Controller looks like:

```
[Authorize]
public class EncryptController : Controller
{ ... }
```

Comment: Should the user ever be able to view the home page if they’re authorised or should they always be redirected to Encrypt when authorised?

Comment: Yes he should can see home page. So it's the problem. If I will just redirect him if he authorized from home page to encrypt he will never see home page.
My answer below partial resolve this but for first enter in session. So still he will only one time see encrypt in session if enter on the site.

Comment: I also tried to write own Authorize Attribute but it will don't resolve the issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your startup to handle access requests:

```
 services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Access-Denied";
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Signout";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

In specific `.AccessDeniedPath` should alleviate your issue with appending it to the Encrypt view...

Comment: Ohh I understand so you offer to redirect to access denied page into Encrypt controller but I need to redirect to Home/Index

Comment: I have tried like this: options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Index"; 
But still get Account Controller Login page.

Comment: + and when user navigate to this page from Home page for example - he should be redirected to Login page, not for Home or Access denied.
So my problem is to redirect only authorized user to /Encrypt by opening the site but let him to see another pages by navigation (like Home).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution.

Make configure like this:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
        });
    }
```

And Home Controller like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated & !HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains("Key"))
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Key", 1);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Encrypt");
            }
            else 
                return View();
        }
```

But it works only 1 time during session, so to get worked this second time need start session again by closing browser.

**So still not good.**

*If I will always just redirect from home page if authorized - he will never see home page. Too not good.*